# Dependent type theory: universes may have a type?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In Dependent Type Theory, as described in Appendix A of Homotopy Type Theory, it is immediate to prove that $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal{U}_i : \mathcal{U}_j$ with $j > i$. So every universe has another universe as its type.

My question is: is it possible to prove $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal{U}_i : B$ for some context $\Gamma$ and some type $B$ which is *not* a universe?

Comment: I'm virtually certain the answer is no.  In general every term has a unique type; the "only exception" is universe cumulativity (if $A:U_i$ then also $A:U_j$ for $j>i$).  But I'm not familiar enough with the syntactic metatheory to be able to give a reference that makes "only exception" precise and proves this.  It's nontrivial because universe cumulativity also gives rise to other kinds of subtyping, e.g. if $P:A\to U_i$ then also $P:A\to U_j$ for $j>i$.

Comment: Note that there are other variants of DTT in which universe cumulativity is explicit rather than implicit.  Then $U_i: U_{i+1}$, but we don't have $U_i : U_{i+2}$ but rather something like $\mathrm{lift}(U_i) : U_{i+2}$.  In this case I believe every term has a literally unique type, and so $U_i : U_{i+1}$ implies that we cannot have $U_i : B$ for any other $B$.